# How to install Tkinter to visual studio 2015

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, visual-studio-2015

I can't seem to get Tkinter to load up in the pip search menu. This is what I have done so far: view>python enviorments>updated/installed setuptools>pip search menu> input"Tkinter" with no luck.Please help, Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

Tkinter should be installed by default, so there's no need to install it.

If you don't have it, open `Programs and Features`, find Python and select `Change`, then make sure that the `Tcl/Tk` option is selected.